# When does Stripe's invoice.paid webhook get delivered in relation to when the subscription starts?

Tags: stripe-payments

We're currently using Subscription Schedules to help us downgrade a customer at the end of the current billing cycle. Once the customer has been downgraded, we want to call the release function to convert the Subscription Schedule back to a normal Subscription based on the downgraded plan they selected. We don't want to wait for this to happen automatically at the end of the schedule because of the way our system is currently implemented.

Our current thinking is that we can rely on Stripe's webhooks to fire a invoice.paid event to know when to call the release function. However, if the webhook was fired too early, the customer would end up being released on to the wrong plan.

So, our question is, **is the invoice.paid event guaranteed to be delivered after the new subscription has started?**

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

No, the order of webhook events [is not guaranteed](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-ordering) by Stripe. Instead the best thing to do would be to retrieve the subscription (or subscription schedule) directly after receiving the `invoice.paid` event to check its status before releasing it.